# browser position.address.postalCode always null

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, position, javascript

I noticed that in FF4 i can use geolocalisation object 
position.address.postalCode to find the postalCode.

When testing on FF10 I noticed that **position.address** is always null, while I can still use position.coords without any problem to find longitude or latitude.

Can someone please tell me if there is simple way to find out postalCode in FF10 with position object?

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(findClosestAgencies);
}
function findClosestAgencies(position) {
  alert("postalCode:" + position.address.postalCode);
  alert("latitude:" + position.coords.latitude);
}
```

my code:

Thank you

Comment: please provide a sample of your code that's not working...

Comment: this code is not working in FF10.     position.address is null
[Break On This Error]  

alert(position.address.postalCode);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the spec:

http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#position_interface

Position is only required to have coordinates and timestamp.  FF4 may have had some additional data, but its not guaranteed to be there since its not part of the spec.  Try using the coordinates with an address finding service.

Comment: in geocoding request, address is required [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests). Is there another way to use google api to find a postal code from the longitude/latitude ?

Answer (score 0):

The address is only available when it's available; there's no guarantee that it will be non-null, in other words. It depends on how much information the browser can get.

If you can only get the lat/long, you might be able to fall back to using another geolocation web service. (Such a service is almost certainly also not guaranteed to return a postal address; if I'm using your website from a boat on a large lake, for example, I might have no meaningful postal address under any circumstances.)